# NotImplementedError: Operator not Implemented in python 3 FDB module

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, firebird

I'm currently rewriting my simple program that needs to work with firebird databases.

Sadly, not all .fdb files are from the same version, some are even from versions below 2.0

in my database wrapper when executing connection i get this error:

```
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 715, in connect
    dsn = b(dsn,_FS_ENCODING)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb\ibase.py", line 47, in b
    if st == None:
NotImplementedError: operator not implemented.
```

while method that throws this exception looks like:

```
def run(self):
    self.conn = fdb.connect(dsn = self.kwargs["db_path"],
                            user = self.kwargs["username"],
                            password = 'masterkey',
                            role = 'RDB$ADMIN' )
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
```

I'm using RDB$ADMIN role so i can add few extra accounts so each thread has his own account to work with.

previous iteration of this program used only one account and it worked perfectly.

This is my first time seeing NotImplementedError. and honestly i have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: The role `RDB$ADMIN` only works with ODS 11.2 or higher databases (Firebird 2.5 or later), you might want to consider upgrading your databases by making a backup and restoring it. I'm not sure if it is related to your current problem though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel might be it, i'll try that as soon as i can.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel took me literally ages, because i got moved temporarily to more pressing project. It was indeed problem with firebird version - sadly i can't update the database due to client's wishes.